# Collection Views lagging with certain strings

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I found something strange while working with a collection view. I created a very simple collection view of customs cells with just one text label. If I populate the text labels with something simple like...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as? CustomCell)?.textLabel = "ASDASDLAKJD"
}
```

then the collection view is scrolls smooth no matter how fast I scroll it.

However, I noticed that certain unique characters cause the scroll to lagg. Here is one character/symbol that I found laggs significantly

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as? CustomCell)?.textLabel = "ᴥ"
}
```

Now when I scroll, the flow is significantly choppy and almost unscrollable. Is there anything known with ios having trouble processing certain unique characters? BTW the fonts are systemFont if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: What if you tried to add it as "\u{1D25}"? is it the same?

Comment: I tried it out and I am still getting the same lagg. I would guess I get about 3 frames per second.

Comment: Are you pretty sure that's the reason of the lagging? Have you tested it on a real device?

Comment: Yes, I am running it on an actual device. Any other string using english letters and numbers fine. Certain unique characters seem to be causing the issue

Comment: Well, it's kind of weird to me. Could you try `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    (cell as? CustomCell)?.textLabel = "ᴥ"
}`? what's the output?

Comment: tried that as well didnt work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I was also fighting with this issue for quite some time. Perfect scroll for English localization. Horrible lags when scrolling with Chinese or Japanese localization.

The problem is view clipping. Seems to be a bug in UIKits font rendering engine.

Check your view hierarchy for views that activate `clipsToBounds`. For example:
UICollectionViewCell -> ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewC -> UILabel
where `ViewB.clipsToBounds` (or `ViewB.layer.masksToBounds` which is the same) is set to `true`. (A common case for settings this to true, would be for round corners)

Disable `clipsToBounds` for all child views of your UICollectionViewCell and try again. If your designer still wants to have round corners somewhere in your cells, you will have to get creative.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried calling .clipsToBounds = false on every subview on the custom cell but I am still having the scrolling issue

Comment: I'm sorry to here that. Maybe you have other CALayer effects active in the cell view stack?